# Handing duplicates in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a table of pixel colors using Python. This table has over 10,000 values and I want to render the images fast (it usually takes around 4 secs to render). Anyway, I want to handle duplicates in a list to make frame loading fast, here's an example:
`(255,255,255),(255,255,255),(255,255,255)` would become `(255,255,255),2`

I've tried making my own code but it's really broken. I've been using python for quite a while now and I still haven't gotten anywhere in getting this script to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? What should happen when the code runs? "to make frame loading fast" - how exactly do you expect this to work? Why should the "handling" that you have in mind for duplicates, matter at all to the speed of the frame loading? "This table has over 10,000 values and I want to render the images fast" - what do the values mean, and what do they have to do with "the images"? **What** images are you talking about, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options depending on if the elements are sorted.

- You can use itertools.groupby as one commenter mentioned above if the **elements are sorted**. This should work

```
from itertools import groupby

pixel_colors = [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (1,1,1)]

compressed_colors = [(color, len(list(group)) - 1) for color, group in groupby(pixel_colors)]

print(compressed_colors)
```

- If the **elements arent sorted** then I think a simple approach like this would work

```
from collections import defaultdict

pixel_colors = [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]

color_counts = defaultdict(int)

for color in pixel_colors:
    color_counts[color] += 1

compressed_colors = [(color, count - 1) for color, count in color_counts.items()]

print(compressed_colors)
```

Be mindful that sorting input and using the first approach may have more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the desired result using the **Counter** function. Here's an example of how you can use it to compress a list of pixel colors:

```
from collections import Counter

def compress_pixel_colors(pixel_colors):
    color_counts = Counter(pixel_colors)
    compressed_pixels = [(color, count) if count > 1 else color for color, count in color_counts.items()]
    return compressed_pixels

# Example usage:
pixel_colors = [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
compressed_pixels = compress_pixel_colors(pixel_colors)
print(compressed_pixels)
```

This code leverages the **Counter** class from the **collections** module to efficiently count occurrences of pixel colors. It then uses a list comprehension to create the compressed list directly.

**Using Itertools.groupby**

It groups consecutive identical elements efficiently. If you prefer using itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby

def compress_pixel_colors(pixel_colors):
    compressed_pixels = []

    for color, group in groupby(pixel_colors):
        count = len(list(group))
        if count > 1:
            compressed_pixels.append((color, count))
        else:
            compressed_pixels.append(color)

    return compressed_pixels

# Example usage:
pixel_colors = [(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)]
compressed_pixels = compress_pixel_colors(pixel_colors)
print(compressed_pixels)
```

Best Approach...

*Both approaches will give you good performance, and the difference in speed is unlikely to be significant for most use cases. Therefore, the choice ultimately depends on your coding style and preferences.

If readability and simplicity are your main concerns, Counter is often a **more straightforward** choice.

If you prefer a more **functional** and **memory-efficient approach**, itertools.groupby may be more suitable.*